# How can I run classes in order regardless the priorities set for each test method?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng.xml

Currently, I'm implementing my tests to run each method separably and what I want to do for example is to run 'CreateUser' class first by it's test methods by priority (priority=1 first and priority=10 last) then move to 'Login' class (priority=1 first and priority=10 last) then to 'LostPassword' class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="xx - TestSuite" thread-count="1" group-by-instances="true" parallel="tests" preserve-order="true">
    <test name="xx">
        <classes>
            <class name="testPackage.CreateUser" />
            <class name="testPackage.Login" />
            <class name="testPackage.LostPassword" />
            <class name="testPackage.Forms" />
            <class name="testPackage.OperatorDashboard" />
            <class name="testPackage.Reports" />
            <class name="testPackage.SubmitterDashboard" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following in your suite file and then retry.

- Retain `preserve-order="true"` in your suite xml. This will cause TestNG to run the tests in the order in which they are found in your suite xml file.
- Remove `parallel="tests"`. TestNG does not honor `preserve-order` attribute if it sees the `parallel` attribute. These two attributes are mutually exclusive.

That should take care of the situation.

Comment: Thank you. but this solution did not work as expected.

Comment: @Adham - Am not sure what do you mean that this solution didnt work as expected.. Please take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/e77780a51ad5534d1f9c15a2466bc762) gist that shows that this works (Just as I had suggested)